# Selecting all cells in an R dataframe that contain a specific character

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe where I want to (1) select all cells that include an * and then (2) make a new dataframe containing only the string before each asterisk.

Below is an example, toy dataframe:

```
X1  <- data.frame(c("Tricho*", "Proteo", "Cyano*", "Gold", "Pseudo"))
X2 <- data.frame(c(" ", "alpha*", " ", "fish", "nitzs"))
X3 <- data.frame(c(" ", " ", " ", "bowl*", "ia"))
Data <- cbind(X1, X2, X3)

Data1 <- Data %>%
  rename("X1" = "c..Tricho.....Proteo....Cyano.....Gold....Pseudo..",
                "X2" = "c.......alpha..........fish....nitzs..",
         "X3" = "c.................bowl.....ia..")
```

I am trying to make a dataframe like this:

```
X4
Tricho*
alpha*
Cyano*
bowl*
```

I think that str_extract_all could do this, or at least return the locations of each asterisk, which I could then use, but my real file is much larger and I am unsure how feasible it would be to use str_extract_all.

I also tried using the following:

```
Data1 <- as.character(Data1)
out <- data.frame(Data1[endsWith(Data1, '*')])
View(out)
```

and

```
Data1 <- as.character(Data1)
out2 <- data.frame(grep('*$', Data1, value = TRUE))
View(out2)
```

but neither of these options worked. The first produced a blank dataframe and the second just produced a dataframe with c("Tricho*", "Proteo", "Cyano*", "Gold", "Pseudo") as row 1 and
c(" ", "alpha*", " ", "fish", "nitzs") as row 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to replace all the other values to `NA` and then `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
Data1 %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ case_when(str_detect(.x, fixed("*")) ~ .x))) %>% 
  unite(X4, everything(), na.rm = TRUE)%>%
  filter(nzchar(X4))
```

-output

```
     X4
1 Tricho*
2  alpha*
3  Cyano*
4   bowl*
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
X4 <- t(Data1)[t(sapply(Data1, grepl, pattern = "*", fixed = TRUE))]
data.frame(X4)
```